# How to display images in Bootstrap carousel using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

So I have a component(Posts) in which a loop through all the posts from the Database. In the component, I 'embedded' another component(PostItem) so I dont have to create a different component for viewing individual entries. Now inside the PostItem component I have another component with the name of 'PostGallery'.

This is the current code that I have in PostItem.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PostGallery from '../posts/PostGallery';

const PostItem = ({
  post: { _id, text, name, files, avatar, user, likes, comments, date },
}) => (
    <article className={_id}>
      <Link to={`/posts/${_id}`}>
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div className="carousel-inner">
            {files.slice(0, 5).map((file, index) => (
              <PostGallery key={index} post={file} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </article>
  );

PostItem.propTypes = {
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default connect(
  null, null
)(PostItem);
```

When posting an entry the user can post URL from images separated by comma which is working just fine. The problem comes when displaying it in the front-end.
This is what I have in my PostGallery component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PostGallery = ({
  post: { files }
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      {post.files.length > 0 ? (
        post.files.map(file => (
          <img key={file} src={file} alt="" />
        ))) : (
          <p>No images found</p>
        )
      }

    </div>
  );
};

PostGallery.propTypes = {
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default PostGallery;
```

I believe this should be easy but somehow its just now working and the console it's not trowing me any errors related to it. So if you guys can help...

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks fine, try to log that file in console and see what are you actually setting as an image source.

Comment: you need to tell react to get those images locally by: src={require('path/here')}